# Beautiful Soup 4 finding text within table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to use BS4 to scrape from [this](http://www.nfl.com/draft/2012/tracker#dt-tabs:dt-by-position/dt-by-position-input:cb) web page. I cannot find the data I want (player names in the table, ie, "Claiborne, Morris").

When I use:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
PlayerName = soup.find_all("table")
print (PlayerName)
```

None of the player's names are even in the output, it is only showing a different table.

When I use:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
print(texts)
```

I can see them.

Any advice on how to dig in and get player names?

Comment: The data is dynamically loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table you're looking for is dynamically filled by JavaScript when the page is rendered. When you retrieve the page using e.g. `requests`, it only retrieves the original, unmodified page. This means that some elements that you see in your browser will be missing.

The fact that you can find the player names in your second snippet of code, is because they are contained in the page's JavaScript source, as JSON. However you won't be able to retrieve them with BeautifulSoup as it won't parse the JavaScript.

The best option is to use something like [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium), which mimics a browser as closely as possible and will execute JavaScript code, thereby rendering the same page content as you would see in your own browser.